# Pixhawk not publishing the local position of my Quadrotor

Tags: quadcopter, gps, px4, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 (ROS Indigo). I run "roslaunch mavros px4.launch" and am able to successfully connect to my quadrotor. I have a working GPS signal and also could see the data being published on "/mavros/global_position/local". However, no data is being published on "/mavros/local_position/pose". When I run the gazebo simulation, data is being published on "/mavros/local_position/pose". What could be the possible solution to this?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258393/pixhawk-not-publishing-the-local-position-of-my-quadrotor/) by [Karthikeya Parunandi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25315/karthikeya-parunandi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi! In order to start the internal ekf2 estimator to see any activity on mavros/local_position/pose, you need to thick  the box on the EKF2_AID_MASK (use vision / use yaw fusion)!
hope it can help

---

Originally posted by [polde](https://answers.ros.org/users/32229/polde/) with karma: 16 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0